# Exclude list of files from find

Tags: linux, shell, find

If I have a list of filenames in a text file that I want to exclude when I run `find`, how can I do that? For example, I want to do something like:

```
find /dir -name "*.gz" -exclude_from skip_files
```

and get all the .gz files in /dir except for the files listed in skip_files. But find has no `-exclude_from` flag. How can I skip all the files in `skip_files`?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I don't think `find` has an option like this, you could build a command using `printf` and your exclude list:

```
find /dir -name "*.gz" $(printf "! -name %s " $(cat skip_files))
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
find /dir -name "*.gz" ! -name first_skip ! -name second_skip .... etc
```

Alternatively you can pipe from `find` into `grep`:

```
find /dir -name "*.gz" | grep -vFf skip_files
```

Comment: Does this work for inclusions as well? I just tested and I got nothing: `included_paths=("./.aws/*" "./.bash_env.m4") && find . -type f -name '*.m4' \( -path "${included_paths[0]}" $(printf " -or -path '%s'" "${included_paths[@]:1}") \)`. When I directly put in the paths into the find command, it does work.

Comment: Prefere `-vw` to match the full line

Comment: What happens if your filename has spaces? I don't think `printf` will work for that?

Comment: I did not realize you can "chain" `-name`s. Outstanding!

Comment: Does this work using the exclude list inside the script? as a Array in this SH-Script. so i don't need care to move two files with me

Answer (score 67):

This is what i usually do to remove some files from the result (In this case i looked for all text files but wasn't interested in a bunch of valgrind memcheck reports we have here and there):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name '*mem*.txt'
```

It seems to be working.

Comment: Works great for me!

Comment: ! expr 

True if expr is false.

Comment: Works great! how does it generalize to multiple patterns?

Comment: Example for if you need to ignore multiple filenames / patterns: `find . -type f ! -name '.foo' ! -name '.bar'`.

Answer (score 13):

I think you can try like

```
find /dir \( -name "*.gz" ! -name skip_file1 ! -name skip_file2 ...so on \)
```

Comment: indeed find can use negation "!" for -name option

Answer (score 6):

```
find /var/www/test/ -type f \( -iname "*.*" ! -iname  "*.php" ! -iname "*.jpg" ! -iname "*.png"  \)
```

The above command gives list of all files excluding files with .php, .jpg ang .png extension. This command works for me in putty.

Comment: PuTTY is a remote terminal (usually using SSH) - whether it works will very much depend on what you're SSH'ing into.

Answer (score 5):

Josh Jolly's grep solution works, but has O(N**2) complexity, making it too slow for long lists. If the lists are sorted first (O(N*log(N)) complexity), you can use `comm`, which has O(N) complexity:

```
find /dir -name '*.gz' |sort >everything_sorted
sort skip_files >skip_files_sorted
comm -23 everything_sorted skip_files_sorted | xargs . . . etc
```

`man` your computer's `comm` for details.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will go through all files (not exactly excluding from the `find` command), but will produce an output skipping files from a list of exclusions.
I found that useful while running a time-consuming command (`file /dir -exec md5sum {} \;`).

1. You can create a shell script to handle the skipping logic and run commands on the files found (make it executable with `chmod`, replace `echo` with other commands):

```
    $ cat skip_file.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    found=$(grep "^$1$" files_to_skip.txt)
    if [ -z "$found" ]; then
        # run your command
        echo $1
    fi
```

2. Create a file with the list of files to skip named `files_to_skip.txt` (on the dir you are running from).
3. Then use find using it:

```
    find /dir -name "*.gz" -exec ./skip_file.sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`find * -name "*.gz" $(printf "! -path %s " $(<skip_files.txt))`

**Working out**

- Assuming `skip_files` has a filename on each line, you can get the list of filenames via `$(<skip_files.txt)`. E.g. `echo $(<skip_files.txt)` should print them all out.
- For each filename you want to have a `! -path filename` expression. To build this, use `$(printf "! -path %s " $(<skip_files.txt))`
- Then, put it together with a filter on `-name "*.gz"`

Comment: this will fail if any of the filenames has a space in it that is unquoted (which it must be if sharing the exclusion list with another utility that expect it that way.)