# How to exclude files from list

Tags: bash, find

I have ~100k files in directory. I need to delete some of them files excluding list of(15k different pattern) pattern:

```
Directory: /20210111/
Example files: 
/20210111/xxx_yyy_zzz.zip
/20210111/aaa_bbb_ccc.zip
/20210111/ddd_eee_fff.zip
...

Exclude.list 
ddd
aaa
...
```

I tried with find:

```
find /20210111/ -type f -iname "*.zip" ! -iname "*$(cat Exclude.list)*" -exec ...
```

Getting error: arguments too long. Because exclude.list have a lot of lines.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude list of files from find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558245/exclude-list-of-files-from-find)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `grep` to filter the output of `find`, then use `xargs` to process the resulting list.

```
find /20210111/ -type f -iname '*.zip' -print0 \
| grep -zvFf Exclude.list - \
| xargs -0 rm
```

- The `-print0`, `-z`, and `-0` are used to separate the filenames by the null byte, so filenames can contain any valid character (you can't store patterns containing literal newlines in your Exclude.list, anyway).
- grep's `-F` interprets the patterns as fixed strings instead of regexes.