# find files and exclude several file endings from the result for a posix shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find, posix

I want to have a single line command to find files recursive and be able to exclude several file types by there file ending.

This is what I came up with and it works.

```sh
find "$path" -type f \( ! -iname "*.txt" ! -iname ".*" ! -iname "*.swf" \)
```

but my problem is:

1. If I want to exclude more files the command gets really long.
2. I would prefer to have the option to put all excluded file endings in one variable to have something similar like this `exclude="(*.txt|*.swf|.*)"; find "$path" -type f \( ! -iname "$exclude" \)` (I know that this code doesn't work but as an explanation what I try to get.)

Like said above, it drives me crazy that I'm not able to find a short single line command which is posix compliant and is able to find files recursive and is able to exclude file by there file ending.

The nearest solution I found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/22558474 but in this solution a file is used to store the to be excluded files. So it's not a single line command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `-iregex` instead of `-iname` (and consult the`man` page on `-regextype` and also on the scope of matching (whole paths versus basenames)). You can then use a shorter syntax, such as `.*/[^.][^/]*\.(txt|swf|whatever|blah)`.

Comment: `pattern='*\.(txt|swf)$'; find "$path" -type f ! -regextype posix-egrep -regex "$pattern"` maybe.

Comment: is `-iregex` posix compliant?

Comment: No it's not. Neither is -iname

Comment: Why does it have to be a single command? You can add a long list of file extensions to a text file and pipe the output of find to `grep -f fileextensions -v`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any newlines in filenames, you can pipe the output of `find` through `grep` to filter out unwanted ones using a regular expression:

```sh
find "$path" -type f | grep -Ev '(^\.)|(\.(txt|swf)$)'
```

Comment: The RE can of course be in a variable.