# Skip folders and files during `grep`

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a folder (`/test`) that contains several subfolder and files (at various level). Inside `/test`, I want to iterate only text files containing a particular string (`$string`), ignoring files and entire directories specified in a file (`$to_skip`) by path. This "exclusion list" contains both files and folder paths as shown below:

```
/test/ex1/fileA
/test/bob/ex1/fileB
/test/ex1/subfolder
/test/jerry/ex2
```

that is, one path per line. What I've done follows, but it didn't worked (the various options are required for other reasons):

```
grep -nriFlI "$string" "/test" | grep -vFf "$to_skip" > "$out"
```

The 1st `grep` actually give me the correct list of paths (any text files containing `$string`), but the 2nd `grep` doesn't filter as expected since `$out` contains all the items produced by the 1st `grep` except the occurrences corresponding the last pattern.

The strange thing is that it works correctly only for the last pattern. For example, if `/test`, among the others data, has the following files/folders

```
/test/jerry/ex2/f1
/test/jerry/ex2/f2
/test/jerry/ex2/foo/f3
/test/jerry/ex2/bar
```

and `/test/jerry/ex2/` is the last pattern specified in `$to_skip`, the paths above (and in general any data under `/test/jerry/ex2/`) are being excluded correctly!

How can I achieve my target?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you put absolute paths into the file `$to_skip` and use `"$(realpath "$root")"` instead of `"$root"` in your  command, it should produce the desired output.

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-do-i-exclude-a-directory-when-using-find

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov unfortunately, following you tip doesn't solve the problem. Anyway, I added some details to my question about a "strange" behavior.

Comment: This sounds like a job for which one might want to use `find` to pass filenames to `grep`.

Comment: @Dominique yes, but I must include the paths to be skipped inside a file, not hardcoded.

Comment: @user9952796: turn the content of that file into a format, understood by `find -prune`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried yesterday something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558245/exclude-list-of-files-from-find, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all information to the question instead of using comments for clarification. If you did "something like" a solution, show the exact commands you used. With the information in the question it is difficult to reproduce the problem. Create a [mre]. Show an example of the files and their contents where necessary, the values of the variables, contents of the file `$to_skip` and the expected result. If your ecample needs a directory structure with several files it would be good to add a shell script that creates all these. Better use `/tmp` instead of `/test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Dominique, putting `-prune` to `find` command will be
a common method to exclude specified dirs/files out of the search result.
Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create the option to "find" such as "-path /test/foo -o -path /test/bar -o ..."
while IFS= read -r f; do
    (( ${#opts[@]} > 0 )) && opts+=("-o")       # 2nd argument and thereafter
    opts+=("-path" "$f")
done < "$to_skip"

find /test \( "${opts[@]}" \) -prune -o -type f -exec grep -niFlI "$string" '{}' +
```

- The array `opts` contains the exclusion list created from "$to_skip"
- The pair of `\( .. \)` is needed for the precedence.
- The `-r` option to `grep` is dropped because the argument list is already
  expanded as recursively traversed files.

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand why you use the -o option

Comment: The `-o` option is for `or`. We want to exclude the path if it matches **either** of the paths in the exclusion list. Then the paths should be combined with `-o`. Is that clear?

Comment: BTW is my script working?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well: I'm talking about the `-o` preceding `-type f`

Comment: When we use `-prune` action, the another action should be put after `-o`. The logical flow control is similar to `if CONDITION then prune; else ACTION`, where the `ACTION` is `-type f -exec grep ...` meaning `if the path is a file, do grep`.

Comment: A shell shortcut statement for `if CONDITION; then ACTION1; else ACTION2` is `CONDITION && ACTION1 || ACTION2`. It demonstrates why `-o` (OR) works as `else`.